# What's the best way of retrieving spam complaint unsubscribe events via the ExactTarget API?

Tags: api, marketing-cloud

Given a period of time, for example, 2 hours, I would like to retrieve subscriber keys who's unsubscribe reason is 'Spam Complaint'. I've tried using various retrieve calls which either return too much data, or too little.

Comment: What objects have you retrieved so far?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews `SubscriberStatusEvent`. The retrievable fields are `SubscriberKey`, `CreatedDate` and `ReasonUnsub` and the filter was between two `CreatedDate`'s. This returns back `SubscriberStatusEvent`'s and I get the `ReasonUnsub`'s it's not efficient as I have to do some filtering on my side to get the `ReasonUnsub`s.

Comment: It would be possible to use a ComplexFilter in order to filter on CreatedDate(Using the Between Operater) and ReasonUnsub in one request.

Answer (score 3):

This worked:

`<par:RetrieveRequest>
    <par:ObjectType>SubscriberStatusEvent</par:ObjectType>
    <par:Properties>SubscriberKey</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>ReasonUnsub</par:Properties>
    <par:Filter xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart">
            <par:LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                    <par:Property>CreatedDate</par:Property>
                    <par:SimpleOperator>between</par:SimpleOperator>
                    <par:Value>2014-02-20T00:00:00.000</par:Value>
                    <par:Value>2014-02-21T00:00:00.000</par:Value>
            </par:LeftOperand>
            <par:LogicalOperator>AND</par:LogicalOperator>
            <par:RightOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                <par:Property>ReasonUnsub</par:Property>
                <par:SimpleOperator>equals</par:SimpleOperator>
                <par:Value>Spam Complaint</par:Value>
            </par:RightOperand>
    </par:Filter>
</par:RetrieveRequest>`